# Why applying transformation to webView dislocate touch events inside webView?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I override `onDraw()` method of `WebView` and apply only  `translate()` to `canvas`(then I need to apply skew and scale methods as well.)
As a result the `WebView` is `translated`,while the touch events are dislocated as much as the `WebView` is translated.for example:
clicking on button it selects text as before transformation it was the location of text.

How could I apply transformation to `WebView` without having such dislocation of touch events?

```
 final WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); 
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);


   private class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       canvas.translate(200,900);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you translate your WebView ?

Comment: @Gordak    The user via browser could add youtube, soundCloud components and apply some transformations (translate,scale and skew) to display all these on mobile app I add WebView, where I load these components and I need to apply all these transformation ,which are done via browser. –

Comment: Okay, but why don't you consider using several WebViews ? Otherwise, I guess you should also monitor the touch events, transform them accordingly and then call the onTouchEvent of the WebView, with transformed coordinates. I'm not sure it's possible though...

Comment: Ok,thanks I'll try .

Comment: @Gordak  changing the transformed  touch events x & y, it doesn't solve the problem .